# Taking an input as dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to take inputs of 10 integers and 10 names from the user and store them as dictionaries. The code that I had written is

```
i=10
while i>0:
    inp1=input("Enter name of student", i)
    inp2=input("Enter marks of student", i)
    i=i-1
```

And i got stuck here.

But when i looked it up on the internet the answer was

```
d = dict(input("Enter key and value: ").split() for _ in range(n))
```

now I did not understand the `.split() for _ in range(n))` part

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is the extra `i` doing in your input calls? This doesn't run.

Comment: What did you not understand? That is a regular generator expression. The `i`th value of the generator is whatever is returned by `input("Enter key and value: ").split()` in the `i`th iteration of `for _ in range(n)`. Then the `dict` constructor operates on these values as if it were any other input

Answer (score 1):

This may be a more readable solution:

```
n = 10
students = {}

for i in range(n):
    name = input("Enter name of student {}: ".format(i+1))
    marks = input("Enter marks of student {}: ".format(i+1))
    students[name] = marks

print(students)
```

In addition, you could work on checks to see if the value is adequate. For example to prevent a user from passing a None value, or a '', or anything not desired.

---

To answer the question still,

Let's take the whole expression and break it down

```
d = dict(input("Enter key and value: ").split() for _ in range(5))
```

dict is for dictionnary

input is for input. Here the user input one string at a time such as 'key value'

split() takes the string 'key value' and break it down into 'key' and 'value'. split() is a built-in method in Python that splits a string into a list of substrings based on a delimiter. So split(' '), split('o'), etc. In your case, split() equivalent to split(None). (I would avoid writing split(None).)

_ is a placeholder to indicate the value of the variable is not needed

range() is another built-in method